# Why am I getting the error Extra content at the end of the document in my xml file?

Tags: xml, codeigniter

Ok, so I am trying to write my first ever XML document.  I am getting an error that says "error on line 10 at column 7: Extra content at the end of the document"... I have no idea what that means.  I am doing this in CodeIgniter/PHP.

```
function conversation($member_id){

        if($this->user['id'] != 0){

            $str = '
                <messages>
                ';

            $message_results = $this->message->result_array($member_id);
            foreach($message_results as $message){

                $str .= '
                    <message id=\''.$message['id'].'\'>

                         <author>';

                foreach($message['author'] as $key => $val){

                    $str .= '<'.$key.'>'.$val.'</'.$key.'>';

                }

                $str .= '
                        </author>
                        <recipient>
                        ';

                foreach($message['recipient'] as $key => $val){

                    $str .= '<'.$key.'>'.$val.'</'.$key.'>';

                }

                $str .= '</recipient>
                        <content>'.$message['content'].'</content>
                        <datesent>'.$message['date_sent'].'</datesent>
                        <status>'.$message['status'].'</status>
                    </message>';

            }

            $str .= '
                </messages>
                ';

            $this->output->set_content_type('text/xml');
            $this->output->set_output($str);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the answer... It's because some of the values in my $message['author'] array were blank!  resulting in, for example, `<id></id>`.

Comment: That's probably not the reason.  The error indicates your output document is not well-formed according to the rules of XML. It probably has more than one element at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

I think your current method (using the strings) leads to possible mistakes. I suggest using DOMDocument to create XML. [Here documentation](http://php.net/dom)